# Use NVARCHAR variables in ASP.NET without declaring their length

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, sqldbtype

i have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(Email) FROM Blacklist WHERE (Email = @email OR (Email like '@%' AND @email like '%' + Email)) AND (CustomerId = @cid OR CustomerId = -1)
```

I want to see if the value in blacklist starts with a @ and if it does i also want to check the parameter and se if it ends with the value in blacklist.

```
(Email like '@%' AND @email like '%' + Email)
```

This works in SqlManager if i declare the variables exaktly as they are in the table like this.

```
declare @email as nvarchar(200) = 'firstname.lastname@xyz.com'
declare @cid as integer = 2

SELECT COUNT(Email) FROM Blacklist WHERE (Email = @email OR (Email like '@%' AND @email like '%' + Email)) AND CustomerId = @cid
```

The value in blacklist is "@xyz.com"

If i remove the (200) part from nvarchar(200) it stop working.

So my question is how to solve this from .NET C# ?

```
db.AddParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, email);
```

Comment: Why are you removing the length? You should *always* declare the length. What is the longest possible `Email` value? Shouldn't your code declaration match the definition of the column in the table? (Blog ref: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)

Comment: If you don't specify the length, then your parameter will default to a length of **1 character**. If you want something else than 1 character, you **need to specify the length**.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad explanation, will try to update the post.
The part where i'm declaring the variables is a test in SQLmanager wich is working. And i want the same query to work from .NET and there is my problem. i Can't declare the parameter with the 200 length from there.

Comment: @FredrikBerggren: **sure you can!** Use `db.AddParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = email;`

Comment: @Fredrik Berggren: of what type is the "db" variable ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what "stop working" means, what happens? Do you get the wrong result, or an error? And why do you remove the length from the declaration?

If you do not declare a variable length for `nvarchar` it is [1 by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) and so it would have the value `N'f'` in this case; I guess you get a count of zero instead of whatever number you expect? Note that `nvarchar(200)`is not "fixed length", it means "maximum 200 characters"; `nchar(200)` would indeed be fixed length.

In any case, it's not really clear what your problem is here: the string length is simply part of the variable declaration in TSQL and it isn't clear why you can't do exactly what you showed above. You could declare the variable as `nvarchar(max)` to avoid dealing with specific lengths, if that's your issue.

Whether or not this is useful for you probably depends on how you connect to the database (you mentioned C# but are you using ADO, LINQ or something else?).

**EDIT:** In C#, you may be looking for the size parameter for the [SqlDatabase.AddParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748773%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) method, if db in your question is indeed an SqlDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (I work with Fredrik) that when the query is executed from C# code, it returns 0, ie not blacklisted. When executed from SQL Managment Studio, where the length of the parameter can (must) be specified, it returns 1, ie IS blacklisted.

Our guess was that the parameter need a specified size (the same as the database field. However, it seems to be working from Management Studio even if the parameter is declared as nvarchar(100).

The question remains, why does the query return 0 when executed from code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, and after much trial-and-error/digging, I think I've figured it out.

I've made a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate this issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0a51/3

Basically, even though you can set an NVARCHAR to strings of any length, it only saves off as many characters as it is defined to have. Since the default is a length of 1, the only character included for your LIKE statement is the first one, in your case, the first character in the email address.

Which is basically what Marc_S said, but with an explanation of why x = 'ab' was only giving us 'a'.

UPDATE

With more digging, I found that this is true of what happens if you write your SQL out like I did in the Fiddle. However, .NET will correctly infer the length of an NVARCHAR from the length of your string and declare the variable appropriately, so it won't have this problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80. So your query in studio is not behaving how your application is behaving.